# Take common between 2 variable list

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Considering the following statement:

```
DECLARE @table_source NVARCHAR(255) = 'ID,PERSONID,ALTROCAMPO,ANCORA,GENDER,LASTNAME,PRIMARYNAME'
DECLARE @table_target NVARCHAR(255) = 'ID,PERSONID,GENDER,LASTNAME,DATES,PRIMARYNAME'
```

How can I take just the common?

Result should be something like:

```
@result = 'ID,PERSONID,GENDER,LASTNAME,PRIMARYNAME'
```

Thank you all

Comment: The *real* problem is you're using delimited values, when you should be using a table-type parameters. What version of SQL Server and what have you tried?. *Also, why do you declare the variables as an `nvarchar`, but then pass it a `varchar` literal?*

Comment: If it were, instead, two columns from two tables then you could just union: `SELECT columnNames FROM table_source UNION SELECT columnsNames from table_target;` Perhaps two temp tables with each of these values inserted (or even one table and a SELECT DISTINCT...) this would be a lot easier to deal with.

Comment: The question shows just two strings, no list of values. If you really want multiple values in a variable, use the `table` type, eg `declare @target_source table (name nvarchar(20) priimary key), @table_target ....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, i solved with the help of LARNU.
As per last question, i assign the result to a variable.
Here is the code:

```
WITH TS AS (
        SELECT SS.[value]
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@table_source,',') as SS),
    TT AS (
        SELECT SS.[value]
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@table_target,',') as SS)
        SELECT @result = STRING_AGG(TS.[value],',')
FROM TS
         JOIN TT ON TS.[value] = TT.[value];
```

Answer (score 3):

***Assuming*** you're using the latest version of SQL Server, and you must use delimited values, use `STRING_SPLIT` and `STRING_AGG`:

```
DECLARE @table_source nvarchar(255) = N'ID,PERSONID,ALTROCAMPO,ANCORA,GENDER,LASTNAME,PRIMARYNAME';
DECLARE @table_target nvarchar(255) = N'ID,PERSONID,GENDER,LASTNAME,DATES,PRIMARYNAME';

    WITH TS AS(
        SELECT SS.[value]
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@table_source,',') SS),
    TT AS(
        SELECT SS.[value]
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@table_target,',') SS)
    SELECT STRING_AGG(TS.[value],',') AS Result
    FROM TS
         JOIN TT ON TS.[value] = TT.[value];
```

If you aren't on the latest version, you'll need to replace them with a string splitter (i.e. `delimitedsplitN4K_LEAD`) and use the `FOR XML PATH` & `STUFF` method respectively for which ever function(s) you don't have access to.

As I said though, really you should be using a table-type parameter, and then this is trivial. *assuming* those are actually column names, then you can do:

```
--Create the type
CREATE TYPE dbo.Object_List AS TABLE (ObjectName sysname);
GO

--Declare variables
DECLARE @table_source dbo.Object_List;
INSERT INTO @table_source (ObjectName)
VALUES (N'ID'),(N'PERSONID'),(N'ALTROCAMPO'),(N'ANCORA'),(N'GENDER'),(N'LASTNAME'),(N'PRIMARYNAME')

DECLARE @table_target dbo.Object_List;
INSERT INTO @table_target (ObjectName)
VALUES (N'ID'),(N'PERSONID'),(N'ALTROCAMPO'),(N'ANCORA'),(N'GENDER'),(N'LASTNAME'),(N'PRIMARYNAME')

--Solution
SELECT ObjectName
FROM @table_source TS
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM @table_target TT
              WHERE TS.ObjectName = TT.ObjectName);
```

Comment: considering the statement you made for sql server, it's possible to have the result like a variable? like @result for example

Comment: You could `SET` or `INSERT` them into a variable, yes.

Comment: Look up `INSERT` and `SET`, @Robertuzzo . They are fundamentals of the SQL Language. You'll learn far more by doing.

Comment: sorry you are right. SET is ok. Set a variable so i can use it

Comment: You can also use `SELECT` to assign the value of a variable; but don't use that unless your query returns a **single** row.

Comment: So what can i use to have the result of the query above inside a variable like
@result = ID,PERSONID,GENDER,LASTNAME,PRIMARYNAME (it's the result of the query)

Comment: That depends on the query you're using, @Robertuzzo . Like I said, you'll want [`INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql), [`SET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-local-variable-transact-sql), or [`SELECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql). All 3 of those are basic commands in T-SQL and you **need** to learn them if you are going to use the language.